# Update view right away after update in Angular/node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm working on a movie app to practice my MEAN stack skills.

So I have the following web page (see below) with a header component. This component shows data like how many users the website has, how many movies and so on. This header is there on every page of the application.

Now, imagine a situation where a new person registers. I would like this component to add 1 to the user count right away so that it shows one more user in the view without having to refresh the page.

I thought this would be the case after I switched to an async pipe in my template, but unfortunately that's not the case. Does anyone know how to actually do this? Screenshots and code below.

**On top you see the header component, for now it has 5 users. When someone new registers I would like it to update immediately instead of just when I reset the page.**

[image: Here you see the header and its data]

**Template**

```
<ul class="stats">
            <li>{{ (websiteStats$ | async).movieCount }} movies |</li>
            <li>{{ (websiteStats$ | async).userCount }} users |</li>
            <li>{{ (websiteStats$ | async).ratingCount }} movie ratings |</li>
            <li>{{ (websiteStats$ | async).reviewCount }} movie reviews</li>
        </ul>
```

**Header component**

```
ngOnInit(){
        this.websiteStats$ = this.movieService.countData()
        console.log(this.websiteStats$)
    }
```

**Back-end node.js route to get all the data**

```
router.get('/getCounts', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('entered back-end');
  var votes;
  var reviews;
  Movie.find({}, function(err, movies){
      if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json({
              title: 'An error occurred',
              error: err
          });
      }
      var amountOfMovies = movies.length;
    User.find({}, function(err, users){
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred',
                error: err
            });
        }
        var amountOfUsers = users.length;
        var amountOfRatings = 0;
        var amountOfReviews = 0;
        users.forEach(function(user){
            amountOfRatings += user.ratings.length;
            amountOfReviews += user.reviews.length;
        });

        res.status(200).json({
              userCount: amountOfUsers,
                movieCount: amountOfMovies,
                ratingCount: amountOfRatings,
                reviewCount: amountOfReviews
        });
    })
  })
});
```

**Addition: service code**

```
countData(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3200/app/getCounts')
        .map((response: Response) => {
            const result = response.json();
            return result
        })
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            return Observable.throw(error.json());
        })
}
```

Comment: What is going on in the movieService.countData()? You won't get updates if you're not subscribed to anything.

Comment: Well, I subscribe using the async pipe in the template. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you're correct that the async pipe will bind to an Observable or Promise directly in your template. I am just curious if or how you are returning your observable from your MovieService. The issue is  potentially in your service.

Comment: Ok, I'll add the code from the service as well.

Comment: I added the service code to the original post.

Comment: Thank you. I believe the issue is you're not in fact returning the Observable, you're returning the response. What you should do is simply return the observable

countData(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3200/app/getCounts');
}

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. Let me try it and then come back to you. Already thanks!

Comment: So without .map and .error right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Assuming you're using httpclientmodule of course.

Comment: ow, I'm still using the old one. Let me try to update it.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend updating. It is simple to do and can really simplify you're code.

Comment: Ok I did, but it still doesn't work as I hoped. client gives me the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'movieCount' of null

Comment: I put a ? behind and that got rid of the error, but it still doesn't update right away after I register a new person.

Comment: That is because you aren't streaming data from your server to your client using http.get requests. Your use case is more conducive to Sockets. Where as your client would be able to subscribe to the movieCount and the server streams updates automatically to the client via the socket. With the http.get request after your first request if fulfilled the request is finalized and there is nothing left for the observable to be subscribed to.

Comment: Your client would need to poll the server (not a good idea) for updates and then make the same http.get request again each time an update is discovered.

Comment: Ok, I see. So what is the big benefit of using an async pipe then? Thanks for explaining everything btw.

Comment: Async pipe is convenient, because it simplifies your code by allowing you to subscribe to the observable directly in your template and in addition manages the observable subscriptions by automatically unsubscribing from all observables once the component is destroyed, preventing memory leaks. Which is a common oversight when people try to manage their own observable subscriptions.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for all the great explanations!

Comment: Sure, no problem. I am happy to help.